# AJAX 504 when calling ASP.NET Web API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, timeout, asp.net-4.0

My AJAX call is returning a 504 error when calling an ASP.NET Web API action.

More info:

Here's my API action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string fileName, int feedID)
{
    try
    {
        // create file...
        return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("Complete."), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteError(ex);
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Content = new StringContent("An error has occurred.")
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my AJAX call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function () {
                $("#lblProgressDownload").hide();
                window.open("Previews/" + fileName);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#lblProgressDownload").hide();
                alert("Error downloading feed preview: " + error);
            }
        });
```

I get a 504 error (viewed in fiddler/ chrome console) when the file takes too long to create. The "error" parameter in the error callback doesn't return anything.

I only get the 504 error when it's hosted - on my dev it works fine.

How do I prevent this 504 error?

Note, I already tried changing the executionTimeout property in my web.config, as well as the ajax timeout. Neither worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP error 504 is a [gateway timeout](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.5):

> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI [...] in attempting to complete the request.

I suspect that means there is a proxy or gateway somewhere between you and the production server, but not your dev server, which is why it fails on the one but not the other.

Your choice is either to make your server code fast enough that it doesn't trigger the timeout, or get whoever is running the proxy server to relax their timeout restrictions (assuming it's something that you or your company controls).

Comment: Considering this proxy timeout limit is beyond my control, is there a way to keep the connection "alive"?

Comment: One thing you could try is setting your [transfer mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx) to use a streamed response. Then write your response handler to start responding with something immediately, even if it's just the http headers, which will hopefully satisfy the proxy's initial timeout. Then you can take a little more time to finish sending the rest of the response stream.

Comment: This is something that needs to be handled on the server side, not in the client. I don't have any experience with this myself, but [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wcf/article.php/c18583/Passing-Large-Files-in-Windows-Communication-Foundation-WCF-using-Streaming-and-TCP.htm) might be of some help.

Comment: I agree the 504 is a timeout... If you've got a large file your trying to transfer and it's taking a while, I wonder if you can return a portion of your file at a time... using something like byte range support for situations where you have large documents.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support.aspx